# Using Nginx URL Rewrite System .. simple, last or break?

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I am trying to change

```
http://site.com/show_page.php?name=terms
```

to

```
http://site.com/pages/terms.html
```

I am normally pretty good with Nginx having setup few sites and done some work on it in the past. This is my URL rewrite, in the conf vhost - I have tried replacing `break` with `last` but no luck.

```
location /pages {
    rewrite ^/pages/(.*)$.html /show_page.php?name=$1? break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dollar sign in your statement does not belong there. A dollar sign designates the end of the string. So nothing can come after it for a successful match. For the rest your rewrite is correct and you can disregard the comments made jagsler about not being able to find the php statement. It is incorrect as clearly covered by the documentation, the last directive will instruct nginx to search for a new location to match. Since the statement rewrites the URL to a different location not matching the location block it is in there is also no chance of looping.

Comment: This is what I thought. I was a little put off originally about the turning off and moving PHP... maybe he did not understand. I appreciate your explanation on this.

Comment: `location /pages { rewrite ^/pages/(.*).html /show_page.php?name=$1? break; }` Is this what you mean, please post the sample

Answer (score 2):

jagsler answer is ok
but one have to keep this in mind:

```
server {
    # you config here (servername, port, etc.)

    location /pages {
        #***modified . = any character, so escape literal dots***
        rewrite ^/pages/(.*)\.html$ /show_page.php?name=$1? last;
        #***the line bellow will only be executed if the rewrite condition***
        #***equals false, this is due to the "last" modifier in the rewrite rule***
        include php.conf;
    } 

    # instead of the php location block also just add the include
    include php.conf;
}
```

So be aware about the behaviour of the modifiers in the rewrite rules
"last" means if the rewrite condition equals true then rewrite the requested uri and jump to the location block that fits the newly rewritten uri.

Another modifier is the "break", wich means if the rewrite condition equals true then rewrite the requested uri BUT DO NOT JUMP, instead stay in the same location block and continue to the next line inside the block

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons it doesn't work. First your rewrite rule isn't correct, change that to:

```
rewrite ^/pages/(.*).html$ /show_page.php?name=$1? last;
```

And the second is that when you rewrite like this nginx doesn't know how to process the php file, because it never reaches the `location ~ \.php` block. You can fix this by putting the complete `location ~ \.php` in a different file named php.conf (or whatever you like) and including this in your server block wherever you need it.

This is probably going to look something like:

```
server {
    # you config here (servername, port, etc.)

    location /pages {
        rewrite ^/pages/(.*).html$ /show_page.php?name=$1? last;
        include php.conf;
    } 

    # instead of the php location block also just add the include
    include php.conf;
}
```